# How to define implied imports in mypy?

Tags: python, python-3.5, databricks, mypy

I'm trying to typecheck notebooks exported out of Databricks. The notebooks are plain `*.py` files with a special comment format to indicate where cells begin and end. There's no reason why mypy shouldn't be able to typecheck these files, except some missing names:

- `spark`
- `sc`
- `dbutils`
- `display`
- `displayHTML`

I know that the `python` command will run a file specified by the `PYTHONSTARTUP` environment variable before dumping you into interactive mode. This is how these names get defined to begin with.

Is there a hook in mypy that lets you define names like these outside the code?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer I came up with. It's dirty, but it works. I'd love a better answer, but until then, here's what works.

The strategy is to use a shell script to prepend the "PYTHONSTARTUP" file to each notebook, and then subtract line numbers in the final output.

typecheck.sh:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

TARGET=$1

# Define the contents of "PYTHONSTARTUP" file inline. This just
# makes it easier to copy & paste this script elsewhere. You could also 
# make it a separate *.py file.
PRELUDE="$(cat <<EOF
import typing
import pyspark.SparkContext
import pyspark.sql.SparkSession

spark = None  # type: pyspark.sql.SparkSession
sc = None  # type: pyspark.SparkContext

def display(expr):
    pass

def displayHTML(expr):
    pass

class dbutils:
    class fs:
        def help(): pass
        def cp(from_: str, to: str, recurse: bool = False) -> bool: pass
        def head(file: str, maxBytes: int) -> str: pass
        def ls(dir: str) -> typing.List[str]: pass
        def mkdirs(dir: str) -> bool: pass
        def put(file: str, contents: str, overwrite: bool = False) -> bool: pass
        def rm(dir: str, recurse: bool) -> bool: pass
        def mount(source: str, mountPoint: str, encryptionType: str = "", owner: str = "", extraConfigs: typing.Map[str, str] = {}) -> bool: pass
        def mounts() -> typing.List[str]: pass
        def refreshMounts() -> bool: pass
        def unmount(mountPoint: str) -> bool: pass
    class notebook:
        def exit(value: str): pass
        def run(path: str, timeout: int, arguments: typing.Map[str, str]) -> str: pass
    class widgets:
        def combobox(name: str, defaultValue: str, choices: typing.List[str], label: str = ""): pass
        def dropdown(name: str, defaultValue: str, choices: typing.List[str], label: str = ""): pass
        def get(name: str) -> str: pass
        def multiselect(name: str, defaultValue: str, choices: typing.List[str], label: str = ""): pass
        def remove(name: str): pass
        def removeAll(): pass
        def text(name: str, defaultValue: str, label: str = ""): pass

def getArgument(name: str) -> str: pass
EOF
)"

# Remember the length of $PRELUDE so that we can subtract the line number
LEN="$(echo "$PRELUDE" | wc -l | awk '{ print $1 }')"

for file in $(find $TARGET -name '*.py'); do
  # run mypy for the two files concatenated together (with a blank line 
  # for good measure)
  OUTPUT=$(mypy -c "$(cat <<EOF
$PRELUDE

$(cat $file)
EOF
)")
  # awk: Take only output where the line number is after the PRELUDE. Also, fix the file name and line number
  FILE_OUTPUT="$(echo "$OUTPUT" | awk -F: '$2 > '$LEN' { line=($2-'$LEN')-1; $1=""; $2=""; print "'$file':" line ":" $0 }')"

  # Remove blank lines from output before printing
  if [[ $(echo "$FILE_OUTPUT" | sed '/^$/d' | wc -l) -gt 0 ]]; then
    echo "$FILE_OUTPUT"
  fi

  # Keep track of all output, so we can decide the exit code
  ALL_OUTPUT+="$FILE_OUTPUT"
done

# propagate errors to the exit code, but ignore errors in the prelude. This 
# makes it easier to use in a CI pipeline.
if [[ $(echo "$ALL_OUTPUT" | wc -l) -gt 1 ]]; then
  exit 1
else
  exit 0
fi
```

Usage:

```sh
./typecheck.sh notebooks/
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did:

1. Create `utils/spark_utils.py` with the following content:

```py
from typing import Any, Optional

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession


def spark() -> SparkSession:
    return SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()


def dbutils(spark_session: Optional[SparkSession] = None) -> Any:
    spark_session = spark_session or spark()
    conf = spark_session.conf.get("spark.master")
    if "local" in conf:
        from pyspark.dbutils import DBUtils  # type: ignore

        return DBUtils(spark_session)
    else:
        import IPython  # type: ignore

        return IPython.get_ipython().user_ns["dbutils"]
```

2. Use these utility functions anywhere in your Databricks notebooks:

```py
import utils.spark_utils as spark_utils

spark = spark_utils.spark()
dbutils = spark_utils.dbutils(spark)

s3_input_path = dbutils.widgets.get("s3_input_path")
df = spark.read.parquet(s3_input_path)
df.show()
```

Please note that `pyspark.dbutils` is a part of [databricks-connect](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-connect.html) package, the standard `pyspark` doesn't have it.